# How can I compile meta node into dwarf binary with LLVM?

Tags: llvm, dwarf

I'd like to know how LLVM does it. For example, I have some Meta Nodes, and use some code to compile it into binary then dump it.

I can't find the part in LLC's source. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but does the chapter on adding debugging information to a programming language in the LLVM tutorial answer your question? http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl8.html

Comment: Nope, I'm not trying to add debug information. I want to convert MD Nodes into binary DWARF.